# Разбор слова по составу - предплечье, прибытие

Tags: морфемный-разбор

Как разобрать данные слова по составу: предплечье, прибытие? Надо ли (вообще) при разборе любых слов выделять мягкий или твердый знаки?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Кажется, так:

1) пред/плечь/[й/э], суффикс j

2) при/бы/ти[й/э], суффикс тиj

Йотированные гласные записываются в звуковой форме, мягкий или твердый знаки просто записываются, но в состав морфем не включаются, например: 
под/ъ/езд/н/ый.

Сверено с "Морфемно-образовательным словарем" 2014 года.